# Careers not allowing me to modify project times

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I have added a number of open source projects I've worked on, and Careers has generated default work times for those.  However, these times are not entirely correct (they show as present while the project is over), and I would like to change them.  Is there already an option for this that I overlooked, or are these dates entirely automatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time frame is dependent on the OSS host and is usually determined by the last push date at the time of adding it to your Careers profile.  We currently don't have any tools to automatically update the project from the host, but you can update the project by clicking on the provider on your profile edit page.

Comment: I was more hoping for a way to fill the information in manually, but this answers the question, thanks.