# Modify Open Source Project Dates

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I have worked on a few open source projects for several years (albeit not continuously), and have moved hosts at various times during this period.

The Open Source section of my Careers profile shows projects as starting from the date I moved to the current host. Please could we be allowed to manually modify the starting date?

There's a similar question at [Careers not allowing me to modify project times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118610/careers-not-allowing-me-to-modify-project-times), but this focuses on the project's end date.